# Using a trained keras model to make predictions without downloading tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, machine-learning-model

Basically, I have a trained `.h5` model (I'm not married to that format, but it's how I inherited the codebase) and want to provide a way for other people in my lab to use this file for prediction. Right now, the call to `load_model()` inside `keras.saving.save` or `keras.models` tries to run `import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf` and throws an error if tensorflow hasn't been installed.

This is annoying, especially since `tensorflow` is so big and it isn't listed as a required dependency for `keras`. Is there a way to load this model for making predictions without the huge overhead of downloading `tensorflow`? Should I be saving it to a different format to avoid the call to `load_model()`?